# Alexa: Can we access the actual voice input by the user inside the lambda function?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

Is it possible to access the text (converted from voice) spoken by the user? Is there a switch somewhere, which if enabled, the text is sent to the skill?

Answer (score 2):

No, we won't get the entire user input.

However, we can capture parts of user speech by using `slots`. There are different slots types and the one which you should look into is `AMAZON.SearchQuery`.

**AMAZON.SearchQuery** slot type lets you capture less-predictable input that makes up the search query.

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "name": "SearchIntent",
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "Query",
          "type": "AMAZON.SearchQuery"
        },
        {
          "name": "CityList",
          "type": "AMAZON.US_CITY"
        }
      ],
      "samples": [
        "search for {Query} near me",
        "find out {Query}",
        "search for {Query}",
        "give me details about {CityList}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

More on `AMAZON.SearchQuery` [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#amazonsearchquery)

There is `AMAZON.LITERAL` slot that passes the recognized words for the slot value with no conversion. But, its's not recommended. You cannot use `AMAZON.LITERAL` in a skill configured with a dialog model